# unicode string equivalent of contain

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have an error when trying to use contain in python.

```
s = u"some utf8 words"
k = u"one utf8 word"

if s.contains(k):
    print "contains"
```

How do i achieve the same result?

Example with normal ASCII string

```
s = "haha i am going home"
k = "haha"

if s.contains(k):
    print "contains"
```

I am using python 2.7.x

Comment: `u'...'` objects are **not** *UTF-8 words*. They are Unicode objects, while UTF-8 is *encoded data representing Unicode values*. It is comparable to displaying an image on the screen and encoding it into a PNG or JPEG file, or a `datetime` object and encoding such objects to a ISO-8601 string. The encoded data and the value are related, but not the same thing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The same for ascii and utf8 strings:

```
if k in s:
    print "contains"
```

There is no `contains()` on either ascii or uft8 strings:

```
>>> "strrtinggg".contains
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

---

What you can use instead of `contains` is `find` or `index`:

```
if k.find(s) > -1:
    print "contains"
```

or

```
try:
    k.index(s)
except ValueError:
    pass  # ValueError: substring not found
else:
    print "contains"
```

But of course, the `in` operator is the way to go, it's much more elegant.

Comment: Found this useful when trying to find one single value but what if we want to search for any value in a list? With contains we would be able to use '|'.join but that wont work with find

Comment: @EduardoPeFez I'm having trouble figuring out what you mean. Perhaps ask in a new question?

Comment: lets say that you want to see if 'string' has either substring 'st' or 'ae'. You would be able to do this with series.contains('ae|st')  then string would return true as it contains 'st'. However with in we can only search either for 'st' or 'ae' but not both at the same time

Comment: @EduardoPeFez Yeah, for that you would need to use a regex, or use `any` with a list comprehension: `any(substr in fullstr for substr in (‘ae’, ‘st’))`

Comment: `bool(re.search('(re)|(st)', fullstr))`

Answer (score 8):

There is no difference between `str` and `unicode`.

```
print u"ábc" in u"some ábc"
print "abc" in "some abc"
```

is basically the same.

Answer (score 5):

Strings don't have "contain" attribute.

```
s = "haha i am going home"
s_new = s.split(' ')
k = "haha"

if k in s_new:
    print "contains"
```

I guess you want to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

### Testing of string existance in string

```
string = "Little bear likes beer"
if "beer" in string:
    print("Little bear likes beer")
else:
    print("Little bear is driving")
```